# Let a group be $G=(\mathbb R,+)$, and set be $X=\mathbb C$, with group action denoted: $a \cdot z=e^{ia}z$. Find orbits.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let a group be $G=(\mathbb R,+)$, and set be $X=\mathbb C$, with group action denoted: $a \cdot z=e^{ia}z$. Find orbits.

How do I approach this question? What do I try to look at?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to look at the definition of the orbit first. And what does it mean geometrically to multiply by $e^{ia}$?

Comment: The task is to apply the definition of an orbit to this group action. You "approach" the question by doing exactly that, and this will involve "looking at" the definition of an orbit and what it means in this particular example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orbit of $z \neq 0$ is the circle with center the origin and passing through $z$, the orbit of $0$ is $0$

Answer (score 0):

You should check that $\cdot$ is indeed a group action, that is, $0 \cdot z = z$ and $a \cdot (b \cdot z) = (a + b ) \cdot z$.

The orbits are $G \cdot z = \{ g \cdot z | g \in G \}$.

Hence $G.z = \{ e^{i x } z | x \in \mathbb{R} \} = \{ z' | |z'| = |z| \}$.